# split String based on regex expression [].[] and [].[] from [].[] + [].[]

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I need to split String based on some condition.

here is my input string

> "([abcd_1].[column] + [ab_cd_2].[column]) / [ab_cd_3].[column]"

the input string will only contain

> A-Z a-z underscore(_) and numbers (0-9)

What I want is

> [abcd_1].[column]
>
> [ab_cd_2].[column]
>
> [ab_cd_3].[column]

I am not sure what condition I have to use.

till now I tried this but not able to built regex expression to split exact string

```
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]");
    String regexpString = "([abcd_1].[column] + [ab_cd_2].[column]) / [ab_cd_3].[column]";
    MatchCollection mc = rgx.Matches(regexpString);
```

Please suggest on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\[[^][]*](?:\.\[[^][]*])*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%5D(%3F%3A%5C.%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%5D)*&i=(%5Babcd_1%5D.%5Bcolumn%5D%20%2B%20%5Bab_cd_2%5D.%5Bcolumn%5D)%20%2F%20%5Bab_cd_3%5D.%5Bcolumn%5D).

Or your way with lazy dot: [`\[.*?](?:\.\[.*?])*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b.*%3f%5d(%3f%3a%5c.%5c%5b.*%3f%5d)*&i=(%5babcd_1%5d.%5bcolumn%5d+%2b+%5bab_cd_2%5d.%5bcolumn%5d)+%2f+%5bab_cd_3%5d.%5bcolumn%5d).

The point is that you may add a non-capturing group with a `.` and your initial pattern, and apply a `*` (zero or more) quantifier to it.

Here is a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/kvA1ST):

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\[.*?](?:\.\[.*?])*");
String input = "([abcd_1].[column] + [ab_cd_2].[column]) / [ab_cd_3].[column]";
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
foreach (Match m in matches)
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

**Pattern explanation**:

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `[^][]*` - zero or more characters other than `[` *and* `]` (may be replaced with `.*?` - zero or more characters other than a newline but as few as possible to return a valid match)
- `]` -  a literal `]` (it is not necessary to escape it outside a char class, but you may)
- `(?:\.\[[^][]*])*` - zero or more (`*` at the end) occurrences of (the `(?:...)` is used for grouping the subpatterns below):

  - `\.` - a literal dot (must be escaped outside a character class `[...]`)
  - `\[` - a `[`
  - `[^][]*` - zero or more characters other than `[` *and* `]`
  - `]` - a `]`

Comment: I tried to use it. it is saying `Unrecognized escape sequence`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande: No idea how you tried that. I tested both the expressions. See [`\[[^][]*](?:\.\[[^][]*])*`](http://ideone.com/PonKME) test.

Comment: yup It worked. I forgot the `@` symbol at starting of the string thanks a lot.

Comment: With C# regex, verbatim string literals are usually the most convenient string literal type to work with, do not forget about `@` when you have so many special chars that need escaping.

Comment: yup will remember that

Comment: can you please tell me how to read it ? I am not sure I understand it properly. It works perfectly but want to understand

Comment: I added the pattern description.

Comment: thanks a lot. will be able to use it more effectivly